# scripts embedded in images

Tags: php, mysql, security

I run a small browser MMO, and I have a problem where a couple users are embedding scripts into their profile images, and using them to make attacks against said users, and my game in general.  Is there a way to protect against this, or do I need to start blocking people from being able to use their own custom images?

If it helps any, it's done in PHP/MySQL.

Comment: more specific details about the nature of the attack would help a lot.. There are a few image exploit that people know of..

Comment: In particular, where do the profile images come from - do the users have to provide a URL, or upload the files?

Comment: the users are providing their own images and urls, and stuff goes bad when people look at them.

Comment: We still have no idea what kind of ‘attack’ exactly you are concerned about. How do you know something malicious is afoot? Are you talking about browser image-parser-bug exploits, JavaScript cross-site-scripting, or really just dynamic images like in Unkwn's answer? (These are totally harmless.)

Comment: They link to the image in their avatar, someone looks at it, and bad things happen to their account.  It's happened to me a couple times, so I'm pretty sure I'm not blowing hot air.

Comment: My guess then is that they are not linking to an image, it would seem that they are linking to a script that is doing the attack, I would suggest either downloading the image locally or only allowing users to choose local/uploaded files.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely what is hapening is they are giving you a link to a script that is building the image and returning it on the fly, there is nothing aside from no allowing users to use external images, that you can do about it, one option to prevent it is to download and store the image on your server as opposed to linking to the external image.

--I decided to provide a sample
This image is created on the fly, the url I'm giving is: http://unkwndesign.com/profilePic.png:
[alt text http://unkwndesign.com/profilePic.png](http://unkwndesign.com/profilePic.png)
now, profilePic.png is a folder that when requested is providing index.php which, using gd, is getting the SO logo, and imposing your IP address over it, to be very clear here I AM NOT LOGING THIS OR ANY OTHER DATA the source for the index.php is:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefrompng("http://stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png");
$font_size = 12;
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,0,0);
ImageTTFText ($image, $font_size, 0, 55, 35, $color, "arial.ttf",$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Since I am returning an image, with a proper extension, and the proper mime-type there is no way to detect what I am doing.
If the server had downloaded my image and stored it locally the IP address would be that of the server, which would ruin the fun of doing it and likely prove to be enough of a discurageing factor to stop the behavior.

Comment: Are you sure your web server isn't logging this by default? :)

Comment: Well of course my web server is logging it, but I assumed that was assumed.  Just like it should be assumed that your ISP logged the connection to my server also.

Answer (score 3):

Try having GD process those images.  If it throws errors, you know you have a problem.  Since image upload is a relatively rare operation, it shouldn't cause load problems to do some kind of arbitrary manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the most common practices for validating image integrity include checking the [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) type, or binary reading the first few bytes of an image. Although these are not the best, it's worth a try to fend some of them off.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the issue where IE will interpret an image with HTML tags in it as being an HTML page, thus allowing HTML and script injection from user-submitted images?

(The bug being that IE will do this even if you tell it the Content-Type is an image/ type. Microsoft have caused endless security disasters with this attempt to be ‘helpful’.)

If so, the usual solution is to serve user-submitted images from a different hostname, one which does not have access to cookies or scripting at the main hostname from which you serve your web application.

Be sure to lock down your virtual servers so that the image server and the app server are each only available from one particular hostname (and the app server must not be accessible via IP address).

This will fix the cross-site-scripting issues. You may still have cross-site-request-forgery requests to deal with, but that's a different problem and can be exploited without image-wrapped script-injection.